# HTTP::Tiny like FTP handling

Tags: perl, http, ftp

I have a module (`Alien::GSL`) which I am working on. Currently it uses `LWP::Simple` to do three calls, an FTP directory listing, an FTP file download and an HTTP file download. The problem is that for only a few calls, `LWP::Simple` has a rather large dep. chain. I tried quickly to switch to `HTTP::Tiny` but as the name should have told me, it dies on FTP requests (anonymous).

Does anyone have any suggestions for lightweight a FTP module. Preferably a lightweight HTTP/FTP module. If not then `LWP::Simple` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

libnet's [`Net::FTP`](http://p3rl.org/Net%3a%3aFTP) only requires the IO modules (standard with perl from 5.004), and itself is pretty lightweight. Libnet only supports FTP, NNTP, SMTP and POP3 however, so you can't use it for HTTP.

Maybe you can use it in combination with `HTTP::Tiny`?

Comment: Net::FTP is included into Perl core, so there is no need to install it.